# Playing Video Files in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a game using Python with PyGame module. I am trying to make an introduction screen for my game using a video that I made since it was easier to make a video than coding the animation for the intro screen.

The Pygame movie module does not work as stated on their site so I cannot use that. I tried using Pymedia but I have no idea how to even get a video running since their documentation weren't that helpful.

Do you guys know any sample code that uses Pymedia to play a video? Or any code at all that loads a video using python. Or if there's any other video module out there that is simple, please let me know. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: "Pygame movie module does not work as stated " how so

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

The latest version of Pygame is still able to play MPEG-1 files. The problem was that there are different encoding of MPEG-1.

The ones I found that works so far is Any Video Converter and Zamzar.com online converter. The downside to Zamzar is that it outputs really small version of the original video.

video.online-convert.com does not work